# What triggers a follower's armor progression?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have noticed that there is an armor progression for each of

Kormac (Templar),

[image: Kormac]

Lyndon (Scoundrel)

[image: Lyndon]

and Eirena (Enchantress).

[image: Eirena]

What triggers the progression?  Is it purely a visual effect or does it have some purpose beyond eye candy?

All images taken from http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_Wiki

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: As the follower levels their armor changes in appearance and I'd suspect quality. I can't provide proof at the moment but I suspect it's level-based (every 10 levels maybe?)

Comment: It most likely scales with the way the Armor Tiers scale in appearance.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Difficulty level, maybe?  Testing required!

Comment: Do you know if their entire appearance is overhauled at once, or if they gain new pieces of gear gradually?

Comment: It's all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It triggers based on difficulty level. Inferno is same as Hell, so you get the last follower tier when you reach hell difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

I've been wondering this myself as I noticed the change shortly after a level up, all my followers changed appearance when they hit level 28. At least they did for me.

As for any effect on combat I haven't noticed any, they seem to deal and receive the same amounts of damage as before.

Comment: I'd say this one is more accurate, as my Templar was at the highest tier at level 48.

Answer (score 1):

The follower armor appearance changes based on level. The first change happens at level 30 (I think, might be 20) and the second change happens at level 50.

Comment: Where did you find this information?

Answer (score 0):

My followers reached level 48 and that marked the 2nd appearance progression
the first was at 28, also what another poster stated above me

Answer (score -2):

There armor groes by the strength of the items u give them. I tried it at my scoundrel and enchantress who both had their standard items. I gave them amulet, 2 rings, new wep eand a follower special and their armor has grown. It doesnt grow by level, i tested it, test it by urself if u dont believe

Comment: Btw i am in nightmare with my demon hunter and their armor was just the way u get them as follower!

Comment: **Do not attempt to vandalise other answers.**